# Launch GUI apps from text-mode tty without loading window/desktop manager

Tags: xorg, desktop-environments, window-manager, headless

Is it possible, in latest Ubuntu distro, to launch GUI apps directly from a tty without loading window/desktop manager?

We need this in situations like:
After configuring an Ubuntu system to boot into text-mode CLI, we just need to launch:

- `gedit` to edit some source files.
- `evince` to view some pdf files
- `firefox` to quickly view some movies for short entertainment

The idea is to have an easy-enough life inside text-mode Linux with quick-and-brief access to `X` stuffs. We only need ***one GUI window each time***.

Comment: This is much like a system administrator who wants to have some brief entertainment while maintaining a server.

Comment: Note that we still keep the Ubuntu installation fully-fledged. No axes plz. :-)

Comment: Where you want to launch these GUI apps? I think, you need to have loged-in desktop session to launch these apps inside. Here is one idea: https://askubuntu.com/a/1040852/566421

Comment: after logging into text-mode, without typing `startx`

Answer (score 3):

That's easy. All you need to do is edit your `.xinitrc` and enable command line login.

**WARNING:** The following steps tell you to do "exactly" what you are asking. You will **not** be able to move any windows with your mouse because there won't be a window manager running. I advise you to at least have a window manager running so that you can move the windows or at least have a tiled window manager such as i3.

If you still wish to proceed despite this warning, follow these steps:

- Install xterm: `sudo apt install xterm`
- Open/Edit ~/.xinitrc and put `xterm` at the bottom and save the file
- Disable GUI: `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target`
- Restart and the system should now start in command line mode.
- Log in and type `startx` and X will start with `xterm` running
- Launch any program you want from there. To exit, type `exit`.
- To re-enable GUI mode, type: `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target`

Special note: You may need to click inside the `xterm` window with your left mouse button before you are able to type. Another way to exit is via pressing simultaneously Ctrl+Alt+Backspace.

Comment: and once you have done that, if you want X to start automatically, then create/edit `.bash_login` and put `startx` in it and now X will start right after you enter your user name + password on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

marko's solution is great. I just wanted a one off solution to run inside of a new virtual terminal without configuring defaults differently and it is as simple as logging in on a new tty and running:
`startx xterm`