# How to simulate logging via login screen in ubuntu 16.04 desktop/server from terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, login

Some ubuntu commands need a user to have been logged in via the login screen. Example is: running `pacmd list-sink-inputs` from the terminal without the user first logged in via the login screen would lead to an error message such as `No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.`

So, are there any commands to run from the terminal to simulate screen loggin in ubuntu 16.04 deskotp/server?

Comment: Here is a workaround for such task: https://askubuntu.com/a/1040852/566421