# How to start up an application like teamviewer remotely, so that I can then connect to the teamviewer instance?

Tags: 18.04, ssh, services, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I am on Ubuntu 18.04, and I use Teamviewer as a way of remotely working on the desktop for GUI reasons. Recently, I made a mistake of accidentally closing the Teamviewer program. Therefore, I am unable to remotely control my desktop anymore.

I can however still ssh into my desktop. Is there a way to load up the Teamviewer GUI remotely, so that I can log in without having to physically be at my computer? I am quite far away from my desktop, and have tried various approaches without success. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Here it is: https://askubuntu.com/a/1040852/566421 This answer is specific for 16.04, but inside is mentioned how to adapt it for 18.04. If it will be worth I could post separate answer here.

Comment: If Teamviewer is set to autostart, you could reboot the computer using ssh. It will come up with teamviewer running.

Comment: Thanks, is setting to autostart doable via ssh only?

Comment: @user321627 if it is doable, I do not know how.